# black header when transition an activity

Tags: android

I have the following slide affect from bottom to top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p"
            android:toYDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="300" />
```

I'm calling "overridePendingTransition" to activate this transition when starting the new activity.

The problem is that I see a small black header on top of the new activity (it's black, not red):
[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/171/devices.png/)

Any idea why?

Comment: it is title drop shadow.

Comment: i am also facing similar problem and finding the solution on it

Comment: i removed the title of activity but it still show me black color so i think it not title drop shadow

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it worked for me

`<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>`

set this theme for your activity